# Is there a notifier on shared_ptr to remove from cache

Tags: c++

I'm having issues designing from a C# perspective.

I've got a class that returns a raw pointer to a class. Using a contrived example:

```
class Subject
{
  private:
   Topic _topic;
  public:
    void  AddTopic(Topic* topic)
    {
      delete _topic;
      _topic = topic;
    }
    void Update()
     {}

  ~Topic(){
       delete _topic;
   }
}

class Student
{
  vector<Topic*> _topicsCache;
  
  private:
    void DoSomething()
    {
      for(const auto & x: _topics)
      {
          x->Update(); //code segfaults
      }

    }
}
```

In the original code at some point somewhere, the Subject class gets deleted.

I'm thinking of refactoring the code without being too invasive to use a shared_ptr instead. Unfortunately, shared_ptr doesn't provide a callback to let me know when I can delete from the topics cache.

I was also thinking of a TopicsCache class to track all the Topics manually. The Topic would take a reference to the cache and remove itself when its destructor it's called. So:

```
class Topic
{
public:
  Topic(TopicsCache &topicCache);
  ~Topic()
  {
     topicCache.Remove(this);
  }
}
class TopicsCache
{
    void Remove(Topic* topic)
    {
        subjects->Remove(topic);
    }
}
```

Is this frowned upon in C++ land?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without seeing how you use your topics cache. Have you considered storing [weak pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in your cache? As long as one other shared pointer exists you can upgrade a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`, otherwise you will get a `nullptr`.

Using the cache would be something like:

```
class TopicCache {
    std::map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<Topic>> _cache;
    public:
          std::shared_ptr<Topic> get(const std::string& name) {
              std::weak_ptr<Topic> weak = _cache[name];
              std::shared_ptr<Topic> ret = weak.lock(); // Try to convert to shared_ptr
              if (ret) {
                  return ret;
              } else {
                  ret = std::make_shared<Topic>(name);
                  _cache[name] = ret; // will store a weak reference to ret
                  return ret;
              }
          }
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks. This is how I envisioned using the cache. But the issue still remains, when Subject is disposed, how do I know when to clear `Topic` from the  `TopicsCache` and `Student` vector? The issue is I don't know how to know clear from the `Student._topics` vector. Are you suggesting passing `TopicsCache` to `Student` then?

Answer (score 1):

The only drawback I see with your design is that Topic now needs to know where it's cached. From a design perspective this looks flawed, so my suggestion is to use a custom deleter for this. This way you move the relation between Topic and TopicsCache to wherever a Topic is created. Let's say your cache is also responsible for creating Topics. You could write something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Topic> createTopic()    
{
    // declare a custom deleter which is invoked when the last shared pointer is destroyed
    auto deleter = [this](Topic* ptr)
    {
        myOnDeleteEvent(*ptr);
        delete ptr;
    };

    return std::shared_ptr<Topic>(new Topic{}, deleter);
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/YW89KP) is a full example.

Comment: Oh yeah, I like this idea. Nice one. Thanks!